# Remove Toolbar title

Tags: android, android-toolbar

MainActivity:

```
package gc.mp3onlinemusic;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.download
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        setupTabIcons();
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
        adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I have OneFragment and TwoFragment classes for tabs. I want to remove title bar. I tried to

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

It is not working

Also I tried to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

in manifest file, it gives stopped error.

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a
>   Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="gc.mp3onlinemusic">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme" parent="MyMaterialTheme.Base">

    </style>

    <style name="MyMaterialTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Finally, how to remove title bar in android?

Comment: where have you added "requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);"??

Comment: just before setConventView line.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to deal with it:

- Programatically:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

- From XML (styles)

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

I think that's all you need to hide the title in the Toolbar without having to do something like `getSupportActionBar().setTitle(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0, 0); // remove toolbar margin from left/right

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get rid of the title in suggested ways, so I solved my problem by removing `android:label` attribute in navigation graph file.

For example:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_bookmarks"
    android:name="some_label" <!-- REMOVE THIS LINE -->
    android:label="@string/title_bookmarks"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want to hide total action bar use this line In your activity class,
"**getSupportActionBar().hide();**"

or

If u want action bar with out title use this In your activity class,
"**getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");**"

Comment: Where? before setContentView or after setContentView?

Comment: after setContentView

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in main activity

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setTitle("");
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved My problem by deleting

in MainActivity.java:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And deleting toolbar from actvity_main.xml
Thanks for all response.

Answer (score 0):

## Title

Use this code in your activity

```kotlin
supportActionBar?.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)
```

Note: This title is not showed in fragments if they have `label` tag in nav graph

---

## NavHostFragment labels

If you use NavHostFragment with fragments the solution above do not disable titles completely. You will see fragment labels. To disable them remove labels from your nav graph.
Before:

```xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/myFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        <!-- Remove the label below -->
        android:label="MyFragment" 
        android:name="com.example.appName.fragments.MyFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

After:

```xml
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/myFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myFragment"
        android:name="com.example.appName.fragments.MyFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/my_fragment" />
</navigation>
```

---

**Question**: May I use one title in both activity and fragments?
**Answer**: You may not disable title but disable fragments labels to have the same title in both activity and fragments